# Firebase Function - Unable to read all child values

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

---

I have a firebase function as per below

```
    exports.shareNotifyNCoin = functions.database.ref('{userID}/mySharedImages/{postID}')
.onCreate(event => {
  const userID = event.params.userID
  const postID = event.params.postID
  const createdAt = postID.slice(0,15)
  const sharedBenefits = event.data.child('sharedBenefits').val()
  const sharedOnFaceBook = event.data.child('facebook').val() 
  const sharedOnTwitter = event.data.child('twitter').val()
  const sharedOnPinterest = event.data.child('pinterest').val()
  const createdByPic = event.data.child('myPhotoUrl').val()
console.log('myPhotoUrl is :' + createdByPic)
  console.log('sharedBenefits is : ' + sharedBenefits)
  console.log('facebook is:' + sharedOnFaceBook)
  console.log('twitter is: ' + sharedOnTwitter)
  console.log('pinterest is: ' + sharedOnPinterest)
    }
```

it is working on a firebase realtime database which has nodes as per below:

[image: data structure]

This function triggers every time a new value is inserted as per the structure in the image. The problem I am having is that when a new node is created then the value of 'sharedBenefits' is being retrieved successfully but not the other child values of the snapshot. Output of the logs is as per the image here.

[image: functions logs]

I am unable figure out the reason why I am not able to retrieve these Child values of the snapshot.

Just FYI, the code that is writing to database is in Java for Android as per below:

```
public static void saveToDatabase(Boolean fb, Boolean tw, Boolean pin, String shareUrl, String shareType) {
    setShareImageFirebaseReference();
    String nodeID = dateTimeStampMilliSeconds();
    myRef.child(nodeID).child(shareType).setValue(shareUrl);
    myRef.child(nodeID).child(FACEBOOK).setValue(fb);
    myRef.child(nodeID).child(TWITTER).setValue(tw);
    myRef.child(nodeID).child(PINTEREST).setValue(pin);
    myRef.child(nodeID).child(MY_PHOTO).setValue(thisAppUser.getPhotoUrl());
}
```

Comment: can post the code that write to database ?

Comment: @Ali - I have edited the question to include the code

Comment: I think each call to `setValue` will trigger your firebase function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe cloud function you wrote is being triggered when you `setValue` of `shareUrl` on `{userID}/mySharedImages/{postID}` node as trigger is `onCreate` of that node and at that time no other values are set, thats why the error.

You should try fanout technique to upload all values at same time or update whole object together not single values.

More about fanout technique [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html)